# window.close() stopped working after updating to Django 4

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, http-headers

I updated packages in my project to latest version, and while testing in Firefox I encountered that `window.open()` assigned to variable returns `Object` - debugged with the code below:

```js
let test = window.open($(e.currentTarget).attr('href'), '_blank', "height=640,width=480,toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0");
console.log(test);
```

And, when I close test (this object) using `.close()` (`test.close()`) it works just fine, but after upgrading packages  (django 3 to 4 version) it stopped working, and `test` variable returns `Window`, not `Object`.

I'm not really sure why it works that way, does Django 4 set some custom headers that cause the `window` close mechanism not work properly? How I should fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, I know how Django affects that.

It's because the browser context is not set and cause are the new security features. To ommit that, set the `SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY` variable to `None`.